# Android debugging app crashes when stepping out of method/function, runs fine when in release mode

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, crash, android-context

I am developing an OpenGL 3.0 game.
When I debug and step through any method/function, my game crashes when I exit said method/function. There is no "unfortunately this app has stopped..." message. This happens regardless of what method I step into.

The app does not crash when I click "Resume Program (F9)" or when I am running it in release mode. 
Galaxy S7 Edge, Android studio 2.1.2. I appreciate any help.

**UPDATE:** I did some digging and the error always seems to happen here:

```
07-11 18:20:12.885 3571-3571/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1468275612.885:4192): auid=4294967295 uid=10242 gid=10242 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=11204 comm=474C546872656164203134313035 exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11
07-11 18:20:12.935 1316-1436/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 9
07-11 18:20:12.935 1316-2149/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{1310315 u0 d0 com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.Main}

                                          [ 07-11 18:20:12.935   649:  680 E/         ]
                                          BitTube(): close sendFd (59)

                                          [ 07-11 18:20:12.935   649:  680 E/         ]
                                          BitTube(): close sendFd (64)
07-11 18:20:12.935 649-13677/? D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7f81b68f88
07-11 18:20:12.945 1316-2149/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{a1afc1b u0 d0 SurfaceView} from container Window{1310315 u0 d0 com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.Main}
07-11 18:20:12.945 649-676/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3191 Removed TurfaceView (6/15)
07-11 18:20:12.945 1316-2868/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.mydomain.myapp (pid 11149)(adj 0) has died(76,1451)
07-11 18:20:12.945 1316-2868/? D/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.mydomain.myapp, Auto Run ON
07-11 18:20:12.955 1316-2149/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 11149
07-11 18:20:12.945 1316-2868/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{97d6b79 u0 com.mydomain.ccc/.Main t693}: app died, no saved state
07-11 18:20:12.945 1316-2868/? W/VirtualScreenManagerService: failed to move task TaskRecord{7e33ef7 #693 A=com.mydomain.myapp U=0 sz=1}
07-11 18:20:12.965 649-2118/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3190 Removed Nain (7/14)
07-11 18:20:12.965 649-2119/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3190 Removed Nain (-2/14)
07-11 18:20:12.975 1316-2747/? W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@80ce62a does not exist
                                                at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:14791)
                                                at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:14782)
                                                at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1764)
                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:558)
07-11 18:20:12.975 649-649/? D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7fc1bc50f8
07-11 18:20:12.975 1316-2747/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: null
```

I'm not exactly sure what all this means, but am I mishandling my android_context? Or EGL_Context? I'm very much at a loss since I can create a dummy method for Main and call it before instantiating my SurfaceView derivative class, step through the dummy method and the error still happens. I thought ist had something to do with the full-screen code I inserted but removed it and no go. I read that sig=11 has something to do with native memory limits being exceeded (in my case, I don't know why that would  be) and besides that, I'm truly lost.

**UPDATE:** I removed anything related to openGL and simply set the content view to "R.layout.activity_main"

Again When I step through onCreate() I get the following on exiting the method:

```
07-11 19:10:38.685 3571-3571/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1468278638.685:4200): auid=4294967295 uid=10242 gid=10242 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=17575 comm="urce.myapp" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11
07-11 19:10:38.725 995-995/? I/Zygote: Process 17575 exited due to signal (11)
07-11 19:10:38.725 1316-2149/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.mydomain.myapp (pid 17575)(adj 0) has died(134,1373)
07-11 19:10:38.725 1316-2149/? D/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.mydomain.myapp, Auto Run ON
07-11 19:10:38.735 1316-2149/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1316  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@18
07-11 19:10:38.735 1316-2149/? D/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
07-11 19:10:38.745 1316-2149/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 17802:com.mydomain.myapp/u0a242 for activity com.mydomain.myapp/.Main
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? E/Zygote: v2
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10242
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0011
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.mydomain.myapp 
07-11 19:10:38.745 17802-17802/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-11 19:10:38.775 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
07-11 19:10:38.775 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
07-11 19:10:38.775 1316-3610/? D/ActivityManager:  Launching com.mydomain.myapp, updated priority
07-11 19:10:38.785 1316-1316/? D/GameManagerService: NotifyRunnable. pkg: com.mydomain.myapp, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
07-11 19:10:38.785 1316-1506/? V/MARsPolicyManager: updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- com.mydomain.myapp
07-11 19:10:38.795 2460-2460/? V/CenterBarWindowService: noteResumeComponent  /arrangeState : 0
07-11 19:10:38.795 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
07-11 19:10:38.795 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
07-11 19:10:38.795 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.mydomain.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.mydomain.myapp rsrc of package com.mydomain.myapp
07-11 19:10:38.805 1316-3488/? I/InjectionManagerService -AppFeature: getCoreFeaturePkgList :[]
07-11 19:10:38.805 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
07-11 19:10:38.805 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
07-11 19:10:38.805 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
07-11 19:10:38.805 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mydomain.myapp-1/lib/arm64
07-11 19:10:38.865 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mydomain.myapp-1/lib/arm64
07-11 19:10:38.875 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
07-11 19:10:38.875 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.mydomain.myapp
07-11 19:10:38.875 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.mydomain.myapp, Feature store :{}
07-11 19:10:38.875 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
07-11 19:10:38.925 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.mydomain.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.mydomain.myapp rsrc of package com.mydomain.myapp
07-11 19:10:38.925 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
07-11 19:10:38.935 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.mydomain.myapp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.mydomain.myapp rsrc of package com.mydomain.myapp
07-11 19:10:38.975 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-11 19:10:39.015 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
07-11 19:10:39.015 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.mydomain.myapp.Main isFragment :false
07-11 19:10:39.025 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
07-11 19:10:39.025 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{31effa1 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
07-11 19:10:39.025 17802-17826/com.mydomain.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-11 19:10:39.025 1316-2153/? D/ISSUE_DEBUG: InputChannelName : ae3809e com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.Main
07-11 19:10:39.035 1316-3610/? D/ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isFloatingActivity() false isHomeActivity() false
07-11 19:10:39.035 1316-3610/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: postActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
07-11 19:10:39.035 1316-1316/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: handleActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
07-11 19:10:39.035 1316-1316/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: Shared devices show user statefalse
07-11 19:10:39.035 17800-17800/? I/FIPS_bssl: FIPS approved mode (1) | 17800 | app_process
07-11 19:10:39.045 1316-2281/? D/MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.mydomain.myapp    className : com.mydomain.myapp.Main
07-11 19:10:39.045 649-649/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3242 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=404, Nain
07-11 19:10:39.045 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: readGMSProperty: start
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: readGMSProperty: already setted!!
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: propertySet: couldn't set property (it is from app)
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: readGMSProperty: could not set the property(default)!!
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: propertySet: couldn't set property (it is from app)
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: propertySet: couldn't set property (it is from app)
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: propertySet: couldn't set property (it is from app)
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: propertySet: couldn't set property (it is from app)
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: readGMSProperty: end
07-11 19:10:39.055 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: addProductProperty: start
07-11 19:10:39.055 1316-3131/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: 17802
07-11 19:10:39.065 1316-1592/? D/PointerIcon: setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001 iconType:101 flag:0 pid:1316 uid:1000
07-11 19:10:39.065 1316-1592/? D/PointerIcon: setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
07-11 19:10:39.065 17802-17826/com.mydomain.myapp I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : c0299d7, I241dab1ec4
                                                                Build Date                       : 01/25/16
                                                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                Local Branch                     : 
                                                                Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.HB.1.1.1.06.00.01.063.117
                                                                Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
07-11 19:10:39.065 17802-17826/com.mydomain.myapp D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f636bf188
07-11 19:10:39.065 17802-17826/com.mydomain.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-11 19:10:39.075 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
07-11 19:10:39.075 1316-3606/? D/InputMethodManagerService: windowGainedFocus mCurrentFocusedUserId - 0 and mSecureKeypadEnabled-false
07-11 19:10:39.085 17800-17800/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
07-11 19:10:39.085 19869-19869/? D/SamsungIME: IMPL finishInput
07-11 19:10:39.085 19869-19869/? D/SamsungIME: SwiftKeyWrapper writeDBdataToFileOnFinishInput
07-11 19:10:39.085 19869-19869/? D/SamsungIME: saveAndClear +
07-11 19:10:39.085 19869-19869/? D/SamsungIME: saveAndClear -
07-11 19:10:39.085 19869-19869/? D/SamsungIME: onStartInput: No inputType, No imeOption, isInputViewShown = false, isExtractViewShown = false, isShowInputRequested = false, isConfigChanged = false
07-11 19:10:39.105 17800-17800/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
07-11 19:10:39.115 1316-1435/? V/WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{ae3809e u0 d0 com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.Main}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
07-11 19:10:39.115 17802-17802/com.mydomain.myapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12b5b33 time:193631312
07-11 19:10:39.115 17800-17800/? E/AffinityControl: AffinityControl: registerfunction enter
07-11 19:10:39.115 1316-1592/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
07-11 19:10:39.115 1316-1316/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
07-11 19:10:39.115 1316-1592/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.mydomain.myapp/.Main: +14s327ms
07-11 19:10:39.115 1316-1316/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
07-11 19:10:39.125 1316-1592/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1316  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@18
07-11 19:10:39.125 649-649/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7fc1bc4ff8
07-11 19:10:39.125 1316-1592/? D/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()
07-11 19:10:39.125 1316-1592/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{b5e6aaf u0 com.mydomain.myapp/.Main t703} time:193631326
07-11 19:10:39.125 1316-1592/? D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
07-11 19:10:39.125 17800-17800/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-2281/? I/MdnieScenarioControlService: mGameModeLauncher : false
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-1506/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1316  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@24
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-3256/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.mydomain.myapp appid=10242 user=0: from pid 17800
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-3256/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 17802:com.mydomain.myapp/u0a242 (adj 0): stop com.mydomain.myapp cause from pid 17800
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-3256/? D/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.mydomain.myapp, Auto Run ON
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-3256/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{b5e6aaf u0 com.mydomain.myapp/.Main t703}: app died, no saved state
07-11 19:10:39.145 1316-3256/? W/VirtualScreenManagerService: failed to move task TaskRecord{40308aa #703 A=com.mydomain.myapp U=0 sz=1}
07-11 19:10:39.155 1316-2281/? I/MdnieScenarioControlService: setUIMode
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{fe4a2db token=android.os.BinderProxy@4dc0fce {com.pandora.android/com.pandora.android.activity.HomeDrawerActivity}} show : false
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager: Stopping in LoaderManager{e5a4178 in a{d009c4}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager:   Stopping: LoaderInfo{df210dd #1 : i{922b452}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager: Stopping in LoaderManager{730a051 in a{d009c4}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager:   Stopping: LoaderInfo{3c402a #1 : i{fb04e1b}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager: Stopping in LoaderManager{e266cd7 in a{d009c4}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager:   Stopping: LoaderInfo{3a382e #2 : e{77c1fcf}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 29231-29231/? V/LoaderManager:   Stopping: LoaderInfo{acbb3ed #1 : c{fdc0222}}
07-11 19:10:39.155 1316-3256/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 17802
07-11 19:10:39.155 1316-3256/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application released
07-11 19:10:39.155 1316-1592/? D/PointerIcon: setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001 iconType:101 flag:0 pid:1316 uid:1000
07-11 19:10:39.155 1316-1592/? D/PointerIcon: setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
07-11 19:10:39.155 1316-3256/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1316  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@18
07-11 19:10:39.165 1316-3256/? D/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
07-11 19:10:39.165 1316-2868/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 9
07-11 19:10:39.165 1316-3610/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{ae3809e u0 d0 com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.Main}

                                              [ 07-11 19:10:39.165   649: 2118 E/         ]
                                              BitTube(): close sendFd (54)

                                              [ 07-11 19:10:39.165   649: 2118 E/         ]
                                              BitTube(): close sendFd (73)
07-11 19:10:39.165 649-2119/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3242 Removed Nain (6/15)
07-11 19:10:39.165 649-2118/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3242 Removed Nain (-2/15)
07-11 19:10:39.175 649-649/? D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7fc1bc50f8
```

There was more but I exceeded my post limit.

**UPDATE:** This happens only on this s7 (along with a couple other apps I wrote which both otherwise actually work). I have an s5 that the problem does not exactly occur on but it does seem to still freeze (just not quit). I have another s7 that I'll be able to test on tomorrow.

Comment: I created a new blank application in android studio on both a desktop and laptop and the problem persists on the galaxy s7 edge. I will attempt to debug on a second s7 edge later today.

Comment: Set developer options/usb debugging on the second s7 edge and ran the dummy project, set a break point inside the onCreate() of the main activity...guess what? As I stepped through and out of onCreate() the app exited silently again...I'm at a complete loss and ready to quit.
So far: Tested on 2 computers, 3 phones (2 galaxy s7 edge's [problem persists] and 1 galaxy s5 [no problem]). Is no one else experiencing this???

Answer (score 0):

People are, but AFAIK there's no solution. Everyone's waiting on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198983